# My surfaces only appear after I press close pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to have the ability to move my green cube character while also showing the surfaces on screen, but the surfaces only show once I press close, and when they do my character can no longer move. I know that this is probably something wrong with screen updating but I cannot figure out what. Help would be much appreciated, please and thank you.

```
from sys import exit
screenwidth = 500
import random
import pygame
running = True
gameExit = False
COLOR = (255, 100, 98)
WALLCOLOR = (255,255,0)
SURFACE_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
x = 500
y = 500
vel = 5

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, height, width):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.image = pygame.Surface([100, 100])
        self.image.fill(SURFACE_COLOR)
        self.image.set_colorkey(COLOR)
 
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image,
                         color,
                         pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height))
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
 
    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
 
    def moveForward(self, speed):
        self.rect.y += speed * speed/10
 
    def moveBack(self, speed):
        self.rect.y -= speed * speed/10
 
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
 
# Creating the image surface
image = pygame.image.load('DJ9ZEF.png')
 
# putting our image surface on display
# surface
display_surface.blit(image,(100,100))
 

pygame.init()
 
 
LIGHTGREEN = (0, 255, 0)
 
screenx = 1080
screeny = 600
size = (screenx, screeny)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("End me.")
 
 
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
playerCar = Sprite(LIGHTGREEN, 100, 100)
playerCar.rect.x = 50
playerCar.rect.y = 250
 
 
all_sprites_list.add(playerCar)
 
exit = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
while exit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                exit = True


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] :
        playerCar.moveLeft(10)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] :
        playerCar.moveRight(10)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerCar.moveForward(10)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerCar.moveBack(10)
 
    all_sprites_list.update()
    screen.fill(SURFACE_COLOR)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

wall1size = width, height = (1000, 200)
img = pygame.image.load('bird.png')


coinimg = pygame.image.load('coin.png')
coinimg = pygame.transform.scale(coinimg, (200,200))
screen.blit(coinimg, (850, 195))
empty_surface = pygame.Surface(wall1size)
pygame.Surface.fill(empty_surface, (255, 0, 0))
screen.blit(empty_surface, (250, -50)) 

px = 0
py = 0

wall1size1 = width, height = (1200, 2000)
empty_surface1 = pygame.Surface(wall1size1)
pygame.Surface.fill(empty_surface, (255, 0, 0))
screen.blit(empty_surface, (250, 425)) 
px = 0
py = 0  
running = True
while running:
    pygame.display.update()     
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
            

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

The surfaces aren't showing because you only import them and show them on the screen after your character is drawn and done. This is because your while loop, which your character is being drawn in and updated in, holds up the code in a loop until it is broken out of which happens when you press the x or close the screen. Not until after that while loop is broken will your code import and show the surfaces.

To fix this, you should put the surfaces' updating functions in the first while loop and just put the importing at the top as well.

(I also recommend cleaning up the code a little bit because you have many variables that you don't use and many functions that don't need to be used in succession)

Hope this helps. :D